# COPY FROM in PostgreSQL, only selecting the first three columns with delimiter at the end

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-copy

I have a data file that has values sepparated by '|' character like:

> value1 | value2 | value3 |

```
COPY tableName FROM 'file.tbl' DELIMITER '|';
```

When I try to COPY these values into a table like the above statement it outputs the error:

> ERROR: extra data after last expected column

This is because every line ends in a '|', I really don't want to create an extra column at the end unless strictly necessary because I have to this process for many tables.
So one workaround that people suggest on other questions is to only COPY the first three columns of the file like:

```
COPY tableName (name, location, datetime) FROM 'file.tbl' DELIMITER '|';
```

but this outputs the same error as before.

> ERROR: extra data after last expected column

Comment: The column list clause will not help as you have extra data rather than partial data.

Comment: The program believes there are 4 columns of data instead of 3, only that the last has no values, Wouldn't the list clause filter the columns to only copy the three specified values and discard the fourth blank value? How would you copy values of only the first three columns? @w08r

Comment: No; if there were 3 columns in the source file and 5 in the table, the column clause can be used to select which in the *destination* would be populated.  Can you preprocess the data?  Otherwise create a temporary table to populate and select from it into your final table perhaps?

Comment: Are you on *nix, and if so you can run a sed command to trim the final pipe | character from each file?  `sed 's/\|$//' file.tbl > file.tbl.new`.  Or if this is a one-time thing, add a column just to get the copy to work and then drop it.  `alter table tableName add column junk text`

Comment: @Hambone have you actually tested this? `sed 's/\|$//' test_sed.csv` where the contents of the file are `value1 | value2 | value3 |` yields `value1 | value2 | value3 |`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver -- you're right.  I was using Perl syntax.  It appears you don't need the escape character in front of the pipe character.  `sed 's/|$//' test_sed.csv`